# add element with DOM model before paragraph

Tags: javascript

I want add new input text before paragraph. But it working opposite add after text.
What is wrong at this code?
I use `document.getElementById("p1").insertBefore(node);` with this aim, but without success. Why does this happen?

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding text to a page</title>
            <script>
                function addText() {
                    var sentence=document.form1.sentence.value;
                    var node=document.createTextNode(sentence + " ");
                    document.getElementById("p1").insertBefore(node);
                }
            </script>
    </head> 
        <body>
            <h1>Create Your Own Content</h1>
            <p id="p1">Using the W3C DOM, you can dynamically
                add sentences to this paragraph. Type a sentence
                and click the Add button.</p>       
            <form name="form1">
                <input type="text" name="sentence" size="65">
                <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addText();">
            </form>
        </body>    
</html>
```

**Question:**

- How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- Grab the new sentence.
- Grab the original content.
- Put them both together in a variable.
- Clear the element.
- Slap it back in.

Like so:

```
var addText = function() {
    var sentence = document.form1.sentence.value;
    var node = document.createTextNode(sentence + " ");
    var el = document.getElementById("p1");
    var original = el.innerHTML;
    var newPara = sentence + ". " + original;
    el.innerHTML = "";
    el.innerHTML = newPara;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/5jSza/1/)

Mind you, this is alot of steps, but hey, a million ways to skin a cat.

Of course you could always shorten all of that code up there to this:

```
var addText = function() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =  document.form1.sentence.value + ". " + document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
}
```

[new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/5jSza/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The [`insertBefore` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) needs to be called on the parent node (in which you want to insert), just like `appendChild`:

```
var node=document.createTextNode(sentence + " ");
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.parentNode.insertBefore(node, p1);
```

---

If you want to add sentences *to* the paragraph instead of before it (right into the `<body>`), you would use this:

```
p1.appendChild(node); // insert at the end
// or
p1.insertBefore(node, p1.firstChild); // insert at the beginning
```